# When joining CTE's on generated uuid, returns empty data set

Tags: google-bigquery

Table `ga4-extract.analytics_1234567.events_20220831` has a record type field `event_params` I want to `select *` from this table where field `event_params` which is a record contains the following name value condition: `key = 'page_location'` and value.string_value like '%example.dev%'.

If working with a json field in athena or postgres I would simply do something such as:

```
select jsonfield['event_id'] as event_id
from mytable
where jsonfield['page_location'] like '%example.dev%'
```

I want that equivilent but must be approaching it wrong because this is way too long for what I want. And, it doesn;t work. I cannot rejoin the CTE's back onto each other.

My query:

```
with 

main as (
select GENERATE_UUID() uuid, *
from `ga4-extract.analytics_1234567.events_20220831`
where event_name in ('trial', 'login')
limit 10000
),

dev as (
select uuid, event_name, e.key, e.value.string_value
from main, unnest(event_params) e
where e.key = 'page_location'
and e.value.string_value like '%example.dev%'
),

event_ids as (
select uuid, event_name, e.key, e.value.string_value as event_id
from main, unnest(event_params) e
where e.key = 'event_id'
)

select *
from main m
join dev d on d.uuid = m.uuid 
join event_ids e on e.uuid = m.uuid
```

How can I filter all records in `ga4-extract.analytics_1234567.events_20220831` where `event_params.page_location` is `like` 'example.dev' and then get the corresponding values of event_params.event_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you use `main` CTE - it is being re-created along with those `GENERATE_UUID() uuid` thus when you then join on 'uuid' you get none!

Below is simple proof

```
with main as (
  select 1 id, GENERATE_UUID() uuid
)
select * from main union all
select * from main
```

with output

[image]

> BigQuery only materializes the results of recursive CTEs, but does not materialize the results of non-recursive CTEs inside the WITH clause. If a non-recursive CTE is referenced in multiple places in a query, then the CTE is executed once for each reference. The WITH clause with non-recursive CTEs is useful primarily for readability.

Having above in mind  - below is hacky "fix"

```
with recursive  main as (
  select 1 id, GENERATE_UUID() uuid
), temp as (
  select * from main 
  union all
  select t.* from temp t
  join main on false 
)
select * from temp union all
select * from temp
```

with output

[image]

P.S. Please note - this answer addresses the question/issue expressed in the question's title - `When joining CTE's on generated uuid, returns empty data set`

Comment: OK! SO what should I do! I initially tried just row_number() instead of uuid. How can I rejoin back onto main?

Comment: There's no id field out of the box on this table

Comment: I used id just for a sake of example - it can be any schema ...

Comment: I added workaround in my answer.

Comment: Surely he doesn't even need the CTEs and subsequent joins back again? Just unnest and filter, twice?

Comment: that is why I added `P.S.` at the bottom of my answer :o)

Comment: That's just a case of the title reflecting an xyproblem. The question content makes it clear what he's trying to do, but has misdiagnosed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info here! @MatBailie could you expand on your comment? I'm convinced my approach is 'wrong' for what I want. There 'must' be a more straight forwards way?!

Comment: Agree with [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) here. But still think that first (thus main) question - is why this happens. In my mind, the second (at the very bottom) question should be posted as a new/separate one with all relevant details and it will be answered too

Comment: Should I post another asking 'how' to approach rather than how to get my flawed approach to work?

Comment: I disagree. The question clearly demonstrates the desired logic in the large query, and identifies that it doesn't work. The need is not to materialise the GUIDs, the need is to extract two different elements from a nest structure. In the paragraph before and after the long code, the OP does make that very clear. While the question is badly written (as the title misaligns with the need), answering the title rather than the question body doesn't seem very helpful...

Comment: @MatBailie Conceptually I agree with you. But this is a special case to me - because many users have that issue OP described  - which is wrong expectations about using cte -  and thus I think it is important to voice it as clear as possible and provide respective example(s) - which is what I did!  :o)

Comment: @DougFir Just wanted to offer a suggestion. I'm not familiar with the GA table schema, but for many scenarios I have with BigQuery, there is some column or combination of columns that can uniquely identify a row. A previous colleague of mine used that approach instead of generating "session ID" values when we were aggregating events into sessions of events. We took the event time of the earliest event in the session and concatenated that with the unique identifier of the user who the event related to. That user ID wasn't PII so concatenation was all we had to do.

Comment: I think if there was PII involved, we could have still done this by hashing, with a salt, the user ID before concatenating it. Or, we could have hashed, with a salt, the concatenated value. If you use this approach, you don't need to generate UUIDs. The data queried would remain more stable, enabling easier joins, helping you avoid the problem of an empty data set being returned by your query that involved joins.

Comment: @MattWelke thanks for the suggestion! With the Google Analytics 4 extract, session_ids are an out the box field. Event id is one we added custom. We could use the timestamp of the event for an ID I guess but in this case we sync events with back end, so need that ID! (There's no PII in this extract)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  t3.value.string_value,
        t3.value.int_value,
        t1.*,
FROM    `ga4-extract.analytics_1234567.events_20220831` t1
inner join unnest(t1.event_params) t2 on t2.key = 'page_location'
                                      and t2.value.string_value like '%example.dev%'
inner join unnest(t1.event_params) t3 on t3.key = 'ga_session_id' -- HERE SET YOUR PARAM NAME! In my analytics there is not "event_id" parameter, but there is ga_session_id.
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this now. Yeah event_id is a custom event attribute we added, not out the box.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks a lot! Going to study this code